# Сайт на основном домене и поддомене - разные по содержанию

Tags: seo, dns

Подскажите, чем чревато размещение на основном домене, например site.com сайта автомобильной тематики (к примеру), а на субдомене another.site.com - абсолютно другого сайта, скажем о музыке?

В Сети много споров на эту тему, и однозначного ответа я не нашел. Как это повлияет с точки зрения SEO?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратим внимание на мотивы подобного "разделения". Для чего прибегать к такому подходу? Если ответ - экономия на другом домене, то: а) это не серьёзно; б) и о какой раскрутке может идти речь, когда экономят на основном "имени", ибо это равнозначно (визуально) сайту на бесплатном хостинге. А если же ответ на данный вопрос с этой причиной не связан, то прибегнем к опыту других сайтов с подобным подходом.

Например площадки для личных блогов от Google, LiveJournal и т.п., работают как раз по такому принципу, где каждому участнику создаётся свой поддомен, по адресу которого содержится его блог с тематикой, отличной от тематики других участников. И тем не менее поисковые системы вполне отлично разбираются "что" и "где" искать.

Comment: Спасибо за столь обширный ответ. Мотив довольно прост: хостинг платный, и хостер дает довольно много дискового пространства (1 Гб). Для моего основного сайта достаточно и 10 мб.

Но есть учебный проект, для которого домен отдельно покупать экономически не целесообразно. Вот и думаю, не подпортит ли репутацию  "подпроект" основному сайту.

Еще раз спасибо.